# SOQL query adding OR condition within IN statement

Tags: soql

I have query that written something like this:

I have data for both `Schulz` and `Scholz`

```
List<User> usr = [SELECT Id, Name From User Where Name IN ('Schulz', 'Eric')];
```

The above query works fine.

My question is if someone types `Scholz` I want the above query to be written data as well since I have data for both `Schulz` and `Scholz`

Is there a way to add `OR` within the `IN` clause? if yes how would I do that?

The last option left is to have two(which I want to avoid) separate SOQL query one for `Schulz` and the other is for `Scholz`

Comment: Why don't you just add the third string? `Name IN ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Comment: shoot you're correct, I don't know what I was thinking. thanks for pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your `IN` clause:

```
Name IN ('Schulz', 'Eric', 'Scholz')
```